# App to hold photos and word docs in ipad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

I will have profiles with photos and their resume to show to clients ., how can i store a (say photos and corresponding resume in word format) in ipad., I seen some file managers ., or elase some special apps already available in market??

Comment: There are many, many apps that can do this. Can you be more specific in your requirements? A simple App Store search will find numerous results.

Comment: I am a marriage broker.., I will be having 2 folders Bride and groom., inside each folder for each boy or girl i need 1 photo with name of candidate and in the same folder a word document with same name., Apple dont have file explorer like android or windows., so confused

Answer (score 1):

If you want a file manager app that can create folders and import files from other apps, I think [Documents by Readdle](http://readdle.com/products/documents/) would be a good app for your use-case.
It's free, you can create folders, import from many Cloud-services (Dropbox, Google Drive, Box.com, OneDrive (Formerly SkyDrive)), it also has an iCloud integration.